# Measuring the capacitance of 2 capacitors at a time

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-ide

I need help with my project. In my project, I have two homemade capacitors made from 2 aluminum foil strips separated by a water bottle. I need to detect which bottle is going to become empty as people drink from it. So I plan to use the change in capacitance to detect the empty bottle. I know how to measure capacitance of 1 bottle and detect the change, but I don't know how to do it to 2 bottles at a time. Any ideas how to do this?
Here is the following code, I have been working on.

```
// Initialize Pins
int analogPin = 0;
int analogPin1=1;
int chargePin = 13;
int chargePin1=12;
int dischargePin = 11;
int dischargePin1 = 10;

// Initialize Resistor
int resistorValue = 10000;

// Initialize Timer
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long elapsedTime;

// Initialize Capacitance Variables
float microFarads;
float microFaradr;
float nanoFarads;
float nanoFaradr;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(chargePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(chargePin1,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(chargePin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(chargePin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Necessary to print data to serial monitor over USB
}


void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(chargePin, HIGH); // Begins charging the capacitor
  digitalWrite(chargePin1,HIGH);
  startTime = millis(); // Begins the timer

  If(analogRead(analogPin)>648){
    elapsedTime= millis() - startTime;
    microFarads = ((float)elapsedTime / resistorValue) * 1000;

    if (microFarads == X) // X is an arbitrary capacitance when the bottle is empty and X is not a variable
    {
      Serial.println(" Bottle A is empty");
    }

    digitalWrite(chargePin, LOW); // Stops charging capacitor
    pinMode(dischargePin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(dischargePin, LOW); // Allows capacitor to discharge
    while(analogRead(analogPin) > 0)
    {
      // Do nothing until capacitor is discharged
    }
    pinMode(dischargePin, INPUT); // Prevents capacitor from discharging
  }

  If(analogRead(analogPin1)>648){
    elapsedTime= millis() - startTime;
    microFaradr = ((float)elapsedTime / resistorValue) * 1000;

    if (microFaradr == Y) // Y is an arbitrary capacitance when the bottle is empty and Y is not a variable
    {
      Serial.println(" Bottle B is empty");
    }

    digitalWrite(chargePin1, LOW); // Stops charging capacitor
    pinMode(dischargePin1, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(dischargePin1, LOW); // Allows capacitor to discharge
    while(analogRead(analogPin1) > 0)
    {
      // Do nothing until capacitor is discharged
    }
    pinMode(dischargePin1, INPUT); // Prevents capacitor from discharging
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a photo, a circuit diagram,  and  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code.  This will indicate how you measure capacitance of a bottle.  That may dictate the approach to measuring two at once.

Comment: Do you need to do two at a time? How long does it take to do one? Can you do one after the other? Would that be easier for you to implement?

Comment: @Mark Smith I would like if the capacitor's capacitance can be measured at the same time

Comment: Your requirement of measuring “at the same time” makes no sense: you will never be able to synchronize the measurements to the picosecond. Please, tell us instead how much delay you can tolerate between the measurements. Do they have to be done in the millisecond? In the same microsecond?

Comment: If you know how to do one bottle you already know how to do two bottles. The second bottle is identical to the first (just change your pins / variables). Making a `class` is a good way of abstracting repeated complex code like this.

Comment: I have pasted the code. However unable to reformat it.

Comment: I just reformatted the code, now the edit is gone...

Comment: @Edgar Bonet, I realise that it is impossible to coordinate  the measurements.  Sorry for the request. It would be fine if there is a time difference of 30 seconds or so between each measurement.  I have tried to achieve it through my code. Thanks.

Comment: Taking a closer look at this... your approach is completely flawed. You expect a capacitance change in the tens of picofarads, maybe 100 pF _at most_. With a 10 kΩ resistor, the charging time constant will be **no more than one microsecond**. Forget `analogRead()`. You need a bigger resistor (1 MΩ should do) and a faster measurement method. Search this site (or the larger Web) for capacitive sensing methods suitable for small capacitances. Once you manage to measure one bottle (and _not before_), you may worry about having two bottles.

Comment: Ah, I assumed with my answer that the one-capacitor version was known to work...

Answer (score 1):

Before we get started, there are a few problems with your code.

First, I wouldn't check for `==648` or `==0`: what if you miss it by a moment and it jumps to 649, or it doesn't quite discharge to 0v?  I'd use `>=648` and `<=2` (or some other similarly low number - experimentation required).

How is your circuit connected?  I can't quite get my head around the charge and discharge pins, but I'll stick with what you have, assuming it works.

You say you want measurements every 30s, but don't say how long they take. (I have no idea of the capacitance of your bottle.)  My code assumes it takes much less than 30s to measure one bottle.  If it takes near to 30s to do one, this won't work.

I'll also assume your code works.  This is a bad assumption, since it won't even compile (capital `I` in `if`) but regardless, that's what I'll assume.

All that being said, here's the code:

```
// Pins connections
int analogPinA = 0;
int analogPinB = 1;
int chargePinA = 13;
int chargePinB = 12;
int dischargePinA = 11;
int dischargePinB = 10;

// Resistor being used
int resistorValue = 10000;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(chargePinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(chargePinB, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(chargePinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(chargePinB, LOW);
  pinMode(dischargePinA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dischargePinB, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(dischargePinA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dischargePinB, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// Measure the capacitance of specified capacitor
float measureCapacitance(int analogPin, int chargePin, int dischargePin)
{
    // Ensure the capacitor is discharged
    digitalWrite(dischargePin, LOW);
    while (analogRead(analogPin)>2) { /* Do nothing */ }
    pinMode(dischargePin, INPUT);

    // Start charging
    unsigned long startTime = millis();
    digitalWrite(chargePin, HIGH);

    // Wait for the capacitor to charge
    while (analogRead(analogPin)<=648) { /* Do nothing */ }
    unsigned long endTime = millis();

    // Start it discharging again, ready for next time
    pinMode(dischargePin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(dischargePin, LOW);

    // Calculate measured capacitance 
    unsigned long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    float microFarads = ((float)elapsedTime / resistorValue) * 1000;
    return microFarads;
}

void loop()
{
    // Measure capacitance of first bottle
    float microFarads = measureCapacitance(analogPinA, chargePinA, dischargePinA);
    if (microFarads <= X) // X is an arbitrary capacitance when the bottle is empty
    {
      Serial.println("Bottle A is empty");
    }

    // Measure capacitance of second bottle
    float microFarads = measureCapacitance(analogPinB, chargePinB, dischargePinB);
    if (microFarads <= X) // X is an arbitrary capacitance when the bottle is empty
    {
      Serial.println("Bottle B is empty");
    }
}
```